# Python DataFrame: Remove duplicates based on condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df with columns `name` and `subject` . I'm trying to remove duplicates for only `math` value after `first` value row for each user

```
            name        subject
    0      mason          first
    1      mason          math
    2      mason          math
    3      mason          first 
    4      mason          chem
    5      mason          math
    6      mason          math
    7       paul          first
    8       paul          chem
    9       paul          first
    10      paul          math
    11      paul          math
```

Final df

```
            name        subject
    0      mason          first
    1      mason          math
    2      mason          first 
    3      mason          chem
    4      mason          math
    5       paul          first
    6       paul          chem
    7       paul          first
    8       paul          math
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way using a condition used to create a cumulative sum column for a grouper and `df.groupby.apply` to check the conditions for each group:

```
c1 = df['subject'].eq("first").cumsum()
out = (df[df.groupby(["name",c1])['subject']
  .apply(lambda x: (~x.duplicated()&x.eq("math")) | x.ne('math'))])
```

---

```
print(out)

     name subject
0   mason   first
1   mason    math
3   mason   first
4   mason    chem
5   mason    math
7    paul   first
8    paul    chem
9    paul   first
10   paul    math
```

Comment: This won't work for this dataframe - Currenlty its removing once one duplicate math

Ex: `data = {'name': ['mason', 'mason', 'mason', 'mason','mason', 'mason', 'mason', 'mason', 'paul', 'paul', 'paul', 'paul', 'paul'], 
 'subject': ['first', 'math', 'math','math', 'first', 'chem', 'math', 'math', 'first', 'chem', 'first', 'math', 'math']}   

df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: @user15590480 updated my answer, please try now. I made a mistake of reading the duplicated values instead of reading the non duplicate(the first value of a duplicate) Thanks for help :)